# How to handle situations, when the read model became out of sync with the event logs?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

When snapshots of aggregates became out of sync with event log i can simply replay my events from early snapshots (which supposed to be in sync). The same i can do when i add/remove new fields or when i modify logic of existing handlers.

In case i need to add new read model (i.e. new report view) i can do the same again - i will replay my events.

But how should i handle situation, when read model became out of sync with the event log? Storing of events and publishing are in one transaction, but updating of read model occurred in another transaction, which can fail. Repeating events from the very beginning can help, but it can take eternity. Do i need a concept of snapshots for the whole read model?

How do you solve this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What would be the reason for failure in event handler? How long is "eternity"?

Read model updates rarely fail (unlike command handlers), since the logic inside is extremely simple. Failures are likely to be caused by transient problems (IO/network outage) and would be handled automatically by the message bus.

However, if read model became corrupted for some reason, then the easiest way to reset it and to stream events through. Even millions of events would take reasonably small amount of time. Plus, you can always use Map-Reduce approach.

I would recommend against introducing snapshots to read models. I think this just complicates the architecture without any significant gains.

Comment: Thank you Rinat! In case of repeating events from the beginning do you use one thread of event handlers? Because in case i will use several worker threads i can receive not correct results (while it will work in production because of domain nature - race condition of several events are not possible when publishing from real users, but possible when publishing one-by-one for several worker threads). Does it globally acknowledged that we should use only one worker thread for processing events from the beginning? Thank you for your valuable answers.

Comment: Good call. I prefer to avoid such concurrency issues by always running no more than 1 thread per entity instance (either commands or events). So we can have multiple threads for event handlers, however each single view *instance* (identified by some identity) will always be handled only by a single thread. Of course, one thread can handle more than one view instance or type at a time. Does this help?

Comment: Thank you! After some days of analyzing your answer i think that i understand mechanics of event handling with multiple worker threads. I appreciate your answers.

Comment: After one year of your comment i have another question related to your comment. You mentioned that "each single view instance (identified by some identity) will always be handled only by a single thread". How do you perform set-based updates for view? Do you address message only to one view instance (thus treating view instances as Pat Helland Entities)? For example, you need to update User Name in every Comment posted by this User. You will handle UserNameChangedEvent once, and update all comments, or you will somehow send UserNameChangedEvent to each Comment view instances?

Comment: I think i found answer on my question. Your approach is well described here: http://abdullin.com/journal/2011/1/19/scalable-and-simple-cqrs-views-in-the-cloud.html. Thank you!